# Problem retrieving email sender in Outlook Interop

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, office-interop, com-interop

We are developing an Outlook 365 plugin that retrieves various parts of the email to create a file.
When the mail in the inbox is sent with exchange we are not able to retrieve the sender. We copied a method in the microsoft manual page but it always returns null.

This is the method:

```
        private string GetSenderSMTPAddress(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {
        string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
            @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
        if (mail == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (mail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry sender =
                mail.Sender;
            if (sender != null)
            {
                //Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
                if (sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                    olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                    || sender.AddressEntryUserType ==
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
                    olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
                {
                    //Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser =
                        sender.GetExchangeUser();
                    if (exchUser != null)
                    {
                        return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
                        PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        }
    }
```

What can we do to retrieve  the sender ? It seems that that manual page is outdated

In any case the step that returns  null is this:

```
 if (exchUser != null)
     {
        return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
     }
```

Comment: So which line of your code does not return the expected value as you step through it?

Comment: What are you expecting after: `if (sender != null) {  ... } else { return null; }` ?   (Please do some more debugging.... )

Comment: HEllo , excuse for the late response,

Comment: I added the null return spot.

Comment: You should also make sue that `exchUser` is a **valid local** exchange user.

Comment: Ah this is very interesting, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sender-related properties are set only after the email has been sent. Make sure that you deal with sent or received items in Outlook. For that you can check the `MessageFlags` bitmask for the `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` flag.

Comment: we saw that the email is an email from EXCHANGE and it is a received email.